# django cms_page does not exist - error message when i click on Pages in admin

Tags: python, django, django-cms

If I open the admin and click on `Pages` under `cms` menu, i am getting this error:

```
DatabaseError: relation "cms_page" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "cms_page" WHERE ("cms_page"."publisher...
```

I thought, may be it is because of `Site` object and created it manuelly.

But i am still getting the same error message, any idea why this is happening?

Comment: PostgreSQL? Did you run syncdb/migrate?

Comment: @alko yeah postgresql. yeah i did run syncb/migrate

Comment: what is output of `select * from information_schema.tables where where table_schema = <your schema name>`

Comment: @alko, honestly, i did syncdb earlier, but now i did again and it solved the issue. is it normal?

Comment: yes, your error meant "cms_page" was absent in your db (dunno why, prob due to some settings), and now you recreated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error

> DatabaseError: relation "cms_page" does not exist

means that "cms_page" relation (PostgreSQL term, meaning table or view) do not exists in your database.

Normally, you create underlying tables for django models with

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

or, if you [use `South`](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/2.1.3/getting_started/using_south.html), with

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Try running appropriate command, and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, migrate itself was failing with this error.
It was an kind of order-of-operations issue with `migrate`, wherein it was trying to migrate models into a table that did not yet exist. I manually migrated cms using:

`python manage.py migrate cms`

Then, subsequent runs of `python manage.py migrate` did not fail on this error.